# Проверка элементов одного объекта с помощью другого

Tags: javascript

К сожалению, возникла трудность для которой я не могу найти решение. Помогите пожалуйста.

Есть объект (может быть совершенно разным, это просто пример):

```
payload = {
    "obj1": "text1",
    "obj2": 123,
    "obj3": "ok",
    "arr1": ["a", "b"],
    "obj4": {
      "result": "ok",
      "description": "desc....4-2"
    },
    "obj5": {
        "obj51": {
            "result": "ok",
            "description": "desc....5-1"
        }
    },
    "arr2": [1, 2]
};
```

Конечная цель: Нужно проверить, есть ли в payload по определенному пути, определенный ключ с определенным значением.

Например, есть ли по пути "payload.obj5.obj51" ключ "result" со значением "ok".

Для этого решил создать отдельный объект с требованиями для поиска:

```
searchOptions = {
    "key": "result", //Т.е. нужно найти ключ "result"
    "path": "obj5.obj51.result", //По пути "obj5.obj51.result" в payload
    "value": "ok" //И значение его должно быть "ok"
}
```

Дальше начинаются проблемы. Проработал 3 основных, как мне казалось рациональных направления:

1. Преобразование payload в json string и поиск нужного через регулярные выражение - получилось очень громоздкое и неработающее выражение.
2. Преобразование объекта в массив с помощью Object.entries() - если в объекте глубокая вложенность элементов, нужна рекурсия для получения всех элементов и это привело меня к следующему пункту.
3. Раскрытие всех элементов рекурсией и попытка сравнить параметры - рекурсия работает только до первого найденного value.

```
Object.prototype.getKeyByValue = function(value, objs) {
  for (var prop in this) {
    if (this.hasOwnProperty(prop)) {
      if (this[prop] === value) {
        return prop;
      } else if (typeof this[prop] === "object" && objs.indexOf(this[prop]) == -1) {
        objs.push(this[prop]);
        var res = this[prop].getKeyByValue(value, objs);
        if (res)
          return prop + "." + res;
      }
    }
  }
}
```

К сожалению, рациональных вариантов решения этой задачи я не знаю (и не нашел).

Возможно Вы знаете рациональный способ решения этой задачи?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Я что-то не пойму откуда такая сложность.

Вам нужно

```
var object = {....}
```

проверить по какому-то пути

```
if (isKeyValue(object, 'obj5.obj51.result', 'ok')) {
....
} else {
.... // нет такого 
}
```

`isKeyValue(object, 'obj5.obj51.result', 'ok')` - по вашей логике - это тоже самое что и

`isKeyValue(object['obj5'], 'obj51.result', 'ok')` - или

`isKeyValue(object['obj5']['obj51'], 'result', 'ok')` - посмотреть и сделать итерацию.

```
function isKeyValue(object, key, value) {
 let keys =  key.split(".");
 let firstKey = keys.shift();
 if (firstKey != null && keys.length > 0 && object[firstKey] != null) { 
   return isKeyValue(object[firstKey], keys.join("."), value);
 } else {
   return object[firstKey] === value ? `${value} найден`: `нет такого`;
 }
}
```

подумайте над решением такого вида.

Comment: Это не сработает, если на пути к искомому "key" не будет хотя бы одного элемента. 

Например:
payload = {
    "obj4": {
      "result": "ok",
      "description": "desc....4-2"
    }
};

Сложность ситуации для меня в том, что искомого пути нахождения value может не быть вообще. А степень вложенности может быть любой. 

Например, нужно значение может быть вложено в массив: 
payload = {
    "arr5": [
        {
            "obj1": {
                "result":"ok",
                "description":"description..."
            },
            "arr2":[]
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Если нет по пути object[firstKey] == null or undefined про100 добавьте проверку. Я показал идею реализации для вашего вопроса и показал наглядно при этом указал подумать над решением такого вида. Если вам удобно перебирать каждое поле каждого вложенного объекта то удачи. Но Ваша задача проста проверить по пути существует или нет. Если там массив то будьте добры учесть такое и в вопросе в приципе. Если подумать то и такое решается на раз два.

Comment: И это ваше спасибо за помощь? Решайте сами, мне отвлекаться и помогать за такое спасибо, извините.

Comment: Честно говоря не понял, что Вас обидело. В любом случае спасибо за направление для мысли.